# How do I mount a logfs-formatted file system?

Tags: filesystem

I am trying to mount a logfs-formatted file system on Ubuntu Server 11.10. Here's what I've done:

```
# apt-get install logfs-tools
# mkfs.logfs /dev/sda5
...
Finished generating LogFS
# mount -t logfs /dev/sda5 /tmp/fs5
mount: unknown filesystem type 'logfs'
```

am I missing a modprobe or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UBIFS is a successor to JFFS2, and competitor to LogFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBIFS). UBIFS does not work with what [many people considers](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubifs.html#L_rednote) flash devices like flash-based hard drives, SD cards, USB sticks, etc.; because those devices use a block device emulation layer called FTL (Flash Translation Layer) that make they look like traditional block-based storage devices to the outside world. UBIFS instead is designed to work with flash devices that do not have a block device emulation layer and that are handled by the MTD subsystem and present themselves to userspace as MTD devices.

The same applies for JFFS2 -- UBIFS is more of a new/improved drop-in for JFFS2. So **if you a trying to install** UBIFS/JFFS2/**LogFS at USB Flash drive it make no sense**. **In case** flash devices that do not have a block device emulation layer like **router or smartphone it does** make sense.

But I guess you not going to install Ubuntu **Server** on top of your router/smartphone or something like that.

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Ubuntu does not compile the LogFS

```
$ grep -i logfs /boot/config-3.*
/boot/config-3.0.0-15-generic:# CONFIG_LOGFS is not set
/boot/config-3.0.0-16-generic:# CONFIG_LOGFS is not set
```

However, you can clone the latest LogFS source using following command:

```
git clone git://github.com/prasad-joshi/logfs_upstream.git
```

The userland tool can be cloned using

```
git clone git://github.com/prasad-joshi/logfsprogs.git
```